# Whitelist a gcp project a gcloud alpha product

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use the new Gcloud Product: Cloud Tasks. It's currently in Alpha. To be able to use, i have to request whitelist of my project for this product. I cannot find a way to do this. Documentations are unspecific. They post a link to google support. But unless you have Silver or Gold support, you don't get any technical help. Meaning, if you have Bronze Level Support only, you get redirected to community sites like this.

My Question: How do i whitelist Cloud Tasks for my gcp project. Whom do i send such a request and how (email, specifiq form provided by gclou?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOUND: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true

Sadly and by mere luck i found this link in the issue section of GCP Repository on GitHub. There Should be a central place for these kind of products with links to whitelist, release schedules, etc.